# ASP.NET Core Web API running in Kubernetes pod generates HTTP URLs instead of HTTPS

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API deployed in a Kubernetes pod, and I'm encountering an issue with URL generation. Despite incoming requests containing "https," the URLs generated within my Web API application are using "http." This becomes problematic when returning URLs to users.

Here are some details about my setup:

The Web API is deployed in a Kubernetes pod.

I am using `HttpContext` to generate URLs within my application.
The Kubernetes cluster is set up with Ingress for external access.
HTTPS is terminated at the Ingress level.

I've checked the following aspects, but the issue persists:

Ingress Configuration:

Verified that the Ingress resource is configured correctly for HTTPS.
TLS termination is properly set up.

Load Balancer Configuration:

Checked the load balancer configuration, ensuring that SSL/TLS termination is configured appropriately.

Headers in Incoming Requests:

Inspected incoming requests and confirmed that the X-Forwarded-Proto header is set to "https."

Forwarded Headers Middleware:

Added ForwardedHeadersMiddleware in Startup.cs to forward headers correctly.

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});
```

Comment: Could you try these suggestion:1)add the trusted proxies or networks2)try manually setting the request scheme based on the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header in middleware

Comment: builder.Services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardedHeaders =
        ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor
        | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedHost;
});

I added this snippet but still it is not working

Comment: could you try like this `var forwardOptions = new ForwardedHeadersOptions
     {
         ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
     };
     forwardOptions.KnownNetworks.Clear(); 
     forwardOptions.KnownProxies.Clear(); 
     app.UseForwardedHeaders(forwardOptions);` set the `UseForwardedHeaders` middleware is called before other middlewares that use the HttpContext to generate URLs.